# How do I use Django's CheckConstraint to restrict a variable at the database level?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to write an application that receives incoming tickets for a small IT department. Currently these tickets come in through a webhook so I want to restrict what comes in at the database level. I want to restrict the `status` variable of the ticket to the choices described in the `ticketStatus` model but the database is still accepting values outside these choices. I've experimented with using `CheckConstraint` but can't quite get it to work.

My code is as follows:

```
class ticketStatus(models.TextChoices):
    Active = "Active"
    Acknowledged = "Acknowledged"
    Resolved = "Resolved"
    Unresolved = "Unresolved"


class Ticket(models.Model):

    dateTimeRecieved = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    deviceId = models.ForeignKey(Device, related_name="Device", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    issue = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="Active")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Device {self.deviceId}: {self.issue}"


    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                models.Q(status__in=ticketStatus.values)
                ),
        ]
```

At the moment, I'm getting this error when I attempt the migration:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I believe this is associated with
`models.Q(status__in=ticketStatus.values)`

I'm currently using Django version 3.2.4

Answer (score 2):

`CheckConstraint` accept two-argument

`name` and `check` both are mandatory argument

Try below this, it works well

```
CheckConstraint(check=Q(status__in=ticketStatus.values), name='ticketStatus')
```

More details can be found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/constraints/#checkconstraint